# Fatal error, cannot continue: The method 'ToStringJS' is not generic

Tags: visual-studio-2010

For the last couple of days, each time I compile my solution (MVC 3 Web Application + several other projects) I get this error in the Error List:

`Fatal error, cannot continue: The method 'ToStringJS' is not generic (Site.css, line 1, column 1).`

Since the error is related to a css file obviously I can run the project.

I don't see errors in the css file.

Even if I delete all css file content, I keep getting this error.

However, the code highlighting disappeared, whilst intellisense and ReSharper keeps working.

I'm not sure where to look for this issue (Googling didn't bring any result, neither Stack Exchange or other specific sites).
It might be a ReSharper issue, but I have actual means to blame R#, so I'd like to start from here, before contacting them.

Comment: I am seeing the issue as well, but I do not have resharper installed. I do, however, have chirpy installed - do you?

Comment: No, as far as I know. At least this excludes ReSharper.

Comment: i have the same issue... so i added a bounty to your question..

Comment: I have the same issue, also have chirpy installed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error you guys are getting comes from [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/) library which is used by [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) Add-In.

I did a short lookup in the [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) and [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/) sources and I found the exact place where the exception is thrown and causes the issue you described.

In the [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/) sources go to `Jurassic\Compiler\Binders` directory and open `JSBinder.cs` file. The problems occurs in the `protected override void GenerateStub(ILGenerator generator, int argumentCount)` method which itself is used to generate another method... yadayadayada. It's quite complex.

Anyway. Here's the code from that file that's responsible for the errors you're getting:

```
// Line 156 (Change Set df266524321d)
// Convert to the target type.
EmitTypeConversion(generator, typeof(object), argument.Type);

if (argument.Type != typeof(ObjectInstance) && inheritsFromObjectInstance == true)
{
   // EmitConversionToObjectInstance can emit null if the toType is derived from ObjectInstance.
   // Therefore, if the value emitted is null it means that the "thisObject" is a type derived
   // from ObjectInstance (e.g. FunctionInstance) and the value provided is a different type
   // (e.g. ArrayInstance).  In this case, throw an exception explaining that the function is
   // not generic.
   var endOfThrowLabel = generator.CreateLabel();
   generator.Duplicate();
   generator.BranchIfNotNull(endOfThrowLabel);
   generator.LoadArgument(0);
   EmitHelpers.EmitThrow(generator, "TypeError", string.Format("The method '{0}' is not generic", binderMethod.Name));
   generator.DefineLabelPosition(endOfThrowLabel);
}
```

If you would like to digg a bit deeper, you might take a look at the `Jurassic\Library\Array\ArrayInstance.cs` and `Jurassic\Library\Object\ObjectInstance.cs` where the `public static string ToStringJS(ScriptEngine engine, object thisObject)` is implemented. Also in the [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/) lib the `CSSLint.cs` file contains a bit of interesting code lines (places where [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/) is used).

I must admit, I don't know exactly why you're getting the "fatal error" or how the problem can be fixed. This would require quite a bit of testing/debuggin effort. Anyone?

Anyway, don't blame Resharper! It's great software ;-)

Comment: Hey, I don't blame R#: is an awesome tool and their support is as well great ;)

About Chirpy/Jurassic, before opening this question, I didn't even know what they were.

Indeed, I have it installed, but I don't remember why or when I've installed it.

Right now I don't need its features, so I can freely uninstall it and solve the issue.

Comment: I would be happy to help on testing, but the issue disappeared in the last 2-3 weeks. The only thing changed in my environment is the version of Parallels Desktop I'm using it (yes, I'm a Mac, but I must use Windows for work ;): I can't believe the issue is cause by that Parallels :)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with CSSLint. You can either download the source code and attempt to fix it, or you can simply disable it.

Go to Tools > Options > Chirpy > CssLint

Uncheck the 'Run CSS Lint' box.

If you encounter the same problem with JS, than disable the JSHint as well

Comment: Exactly, of which environment are your referring to?
In VS2010: Tools -> Option doesn't contain a "Chirpy" item
In R# there are both Tools and Options, but not Tools->Options
These are the two environments I can think about, but I suppose you're talking about something completely different.

Comment: Disabled it, still happening. :(

Comment: @rball: The problem is a syntax error.  See ScottCate's answer.  In my case, it was as a result of writing: 35x instead of 35px

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem, and solved it by fixing some invalid css. in my case the invalid css was (notice the misplaced period?)

```
#exposeMask{.visibility:hidden;}
```

After fixing the typo, everything came back to life.

Comment: +1 Good find! In my case the website template designer was putting in some weird non-ascii symbols in the CSS as part of their "cool" designer signature (something like ascii art but with characters outside the ascii character set). Despite being part of the comments, these odd characters were a problem. Removing the non-ascii characters solved the problem! I am running Chirpy 2.

Comment: Great, I've got a 1320 line css file with the problem. Groan. Let me go looking for the needle...

Comment: Now if Chirpy could only tell you where the source line is for the `ToStringJS` error - that would be awesome!

Comment: In my case it was as a result of writing width: 35x instead of width: 35px

Answer (score 0):

I might be a little late to the party, but I just installed the Chirpy add-in to Visual Studio 2010, and almost instantly started running into these errors.

I went into Tools > Options, then Chirpy > CssLint and unchecked "Run CSS Lint". Tada! No more error.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody facing this exception please go back to your View(s) and remove or delete the commented sections in the View(s). 
**Why**
When the view is being compiled with comments that contain handlebarjs markup "**{{**something**}}**"
then the Jurassic template compiler l'l have a problem compiling thus throwing this type of exception. Yep i kow it's confusing!!